# How To Remove XP Penalty on Heists

Tags: payday-2

I noticed that some heists carry a small percent of XP penalty. My question is how exactly can you remove these penalties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never experienced an XP penalty, but I've read on [the wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Reputation_(Payday_2)) that:

> An experience penalty is automatically assigned to heists that you've played too much in a short period of time. This penalty will increase if you keep playing. Penalties can be randomly added to certain heists on Crime.net as well.

So it sounds like if you farm a particular heist over and over it begins to apply a penalty to the heist to discourage you from playing the same heist, and encourage you to play others.  They can also appear randomly (that's kind of odd to me). I personally have never seen an XP penalty, but I tend to play heists at random, hence why I've never seen it.

I've [also read](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/46476145585700416/) that the cure for the penalties are to stop playing the level with the penalty, and play other heists, especially the ones with a plus sign(s) next to the heist icon on Crime.net.

Comment: Worth noting that the heists with a small + are the ones that you haven't played much. The less they were played, the bgger the XP boost.